# Magento: How to control products displayed by sorted by "Best Sellers"?

Tags: magento

I have a list of products that are getting displyed on the front-end which are sorted by "Best Sellers" option. My requirement is to move some products down which are showing top at the moment. Can anyone please help me, how do i achieve this? Thanks

Comment: How about adding a product attribute to the ones you want to bump down which you can use to factor into the best sellers sorting order?

Comment: Hi Scrowler, I don't want to add any product attribute and want to use the default sort attribute. is there any way that i can sort positions for best sellers in a database table? Thanks

Comment: What's the criteria? Is it randomly chosen by someone?

Comment: No, It's a requirement. We did some test orders on one product for number of times so that product is appearing first in the list when you sort by "Best Sellers" so now we want to move that product very last or some where in the middle. Thanks

Comment: Ok, do you have a formula for the sort order then?

Comment: No Sorry...looking for help on that. Thanks

Comment: I found the solution which is just changed the postions in the bestsellers table (Extension related table) and it worked. Thanks for you support...